# Rest client login for ASP.NET MVC 5 Web API2

Tags: asp.net-web-api, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I have created mixed project **ASP.NET MVC5 +  WebAPI 2 (.NET Framework 4.5.6).** I have implemented correct working API controller.

I would like to protect this controller with `[Authorize]` attribute.
And I have to use ***MS Windowsw Service client*** to consume this API.

**At the moment of connecting to WebAPI it gets redirecting to the login webpage.**

Have I implement special login method **at the API controler itself** or at the `AccountController` of the website?

As I see for the mixed proyect Visual Studio does not generate this code

```
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
   TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
   Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
   AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
   AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
   // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
   AllowInsecureHttp = true
};
```

And instead of it there is another one.

How to avoid it so Windows Service can consume API?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found complete solution here

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/martinkearn/2015/03/25/securing-and-securely-calling-web-api-and-authorize/

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Net.Http;
 using System.Net.Http.Headers;
 using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace Client
 {
 class Program
 {
 const string userName = "someuser@someemail.com";
 const string password = "Password1!";
 const string apiBaseUri = "http://localhost:18342";
 const string apiGetPeoplePath = "/api/people";

 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
 //Get the token
 var token = GetAPIToken(userName, password, apiBaseUri).Result;
 Console.WriteLine("Token: {0}", token);

 //Make the call
 var response = GetRequest(token, apiBaseUri, apiGetPeoplePath).Result;
 Console.WriteLine("response: {0}", response);

 //wait for key press to exit
 Console.ReadKey();
 }

 private static async Task<string> GetAPIToken(string userName, string password, string apiBaseUri)
 {
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
 {
 //setup client
 client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiBaseUri);
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

 //setup login data
 var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
 {
 new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password"), 
 new KeyValuePair<string, string>("username", userName), 
 new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password), 
 });

 //send request
 HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.PostAsync("/Token", formContent);

 //get access token from response body
 var responseJson = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 var jObject = JObject.Parse(responseJson);
 return jObject.GetValue("access_token").ToString();
 }
 }

 static async Task<string> GetRequest(string token, string apiBaseUri, string requestPath)
 {
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
 {
 //setup client
 client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiBaseUri);
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

 //make request
 HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(requestPath);
 var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 return responseString;
 }
 }
 }
 }
```